# Logical connection between two statements on FAQ page seems to be missing

Tags: discussion

Two statements in the FAQ page, of which one follows right after another one, don't seem to me to have a logical connection. Take a look:

Statemet 1:

> For the purposes of this site, any group that identifies themselves as
>   Christian are to be considered part of that set. This is critical!

Statement 2 (follows right after):

> Answers are to be judged based on how well they represent the view or
>   tradition they claim to speak for, not whether or not you agree with
>   that position.

The first statement is concerned about who must be considered to be a Christian on this site, but the second statement, pretty much out of the blue, starts telling us about how user's agreeing or disagreeing  with some position (doctrine) is not relevant to how the questions will be judged on this site.

Shouldn't the second statement also be talking about who is to be considered a Christian here? This way it looks more logical and more "flowing" to me ( I am not talking about the beauty of the language, I am concerned about the clarity) :

Statemet 1:

> For the purposes of this site, any group that identifies themselves as
>   Christian are to be considered part of that set. This is critical!

Statement 2 (follows right after):

> Answers are to be judged based on how well they represent the view or
>   tradition they claim to speak for, not **whether or not you consider
>   the proponents of that position to be Christians.**

I don't discard the need for the second statement in the way it is written now, but it would better if it were placed in another section, a special section on how the question are evaluated on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really ought to read the passage as such (emphasis mine):

> For the purposes of this site **[and evaluating the content found therein]**, any group that identifies themselves as Christian are to be considered part of that set. This is critical! Answers are to be judged based on how well they represent the view or tradition they claim to speak for, not whether or not you agree with that position.

That is, when you see a question or answer that's from a Christian perspective you don't agree with, you ought not to down-vote it, vote to close, or flag it *merely because* you don't think that person is providing your version of a Christian perspective.

If, for example, a Roman Catholic provides an answer self-consistent with Roman Catholic teaching, that's fine and proper for this site even if you think Roman Catholics are wrong and aren't true Christians.

Similarly, if someone asks a question about the doctrine of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints, it's on-topic, even if you disagree Mormons should be considered Christians.

Furthermore, questions like "Are X Christians?" or "Should I consider what X group believes to be Christian?" are off-topic here because the answer is *always* yes for the purposes of this site.

But, if an answer is inconsistent with the beliefs of the group claimed, by all means down-vote it. If a question doesn't make any sense or asks about non-Christian issues (like, for example, if a question asked, "Who would win in a fight: Martin Luther or Brigham Young?" or "I'm a Catholic: can you help me fix my computer?"), vote to close it or flag it.

The takeaway is that content is supposed to be evaluated on how self-consistent it is, not how much it conforms to any one definition of Christianity, because here, everyone's a Christian if they say so.

Comment: Thank you. In fact, it would be really to have those words of yours - [and evaluating the content found therein] - on the FAQ page, right there in the text. Because they connect statement 1 to statement 2 perfectly well.

Comment: Mark, I just tweaked that section a bit. How do you think it reads now?

Comment: @Caleb looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

I think [Mark's analysis](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/863/30) of what that was supposed to mean is right on target. In the interest of making the wording more clear and specific, I have updated that paragraph of the FAQ to read as follows:

> As far as the scope of this site is concerned, *any group that identifies themselves as Christian are to be considered on-topic* and allowed to label themselves Christian. **Answers are to be judged based on how well they represent the specific view or tradition they claim to speak for, not whether or not you agree with that position.** Good answers thoroughly defend a specific viewpoint or accurately describe a broad range of views. Bad answers wrongly represent the view they claim to speak for, are offensive in their demeanor towards other views, or don't stick to answering the question.

Hopefully that better represents what we were trying to communicate.